# Select all rows but only return certain columns MySQL PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

The following query works perfectly :

Select `username` and `name` from `users` table, left join with `avatar` from the `user_meta` table where the `username` or `name` matches the `:search` term.

```
$sql = 'SELECT users.username, users.name, user_meta.avatar
        FROM users
        LEFT JOIN user_meta
        ON users.username = user_meta.username
        WHERE users.username LIKE :search
        OR users.name LIKE :search';
```

But it's only returning one row while there are multiple rows that match in the database.

How can I make this return all matching rows but still only return the `username`, `user` and `avatar` columns in the object?

Comment: returning one result means result only one row or return only one row with only `name`, `username` and `user_meta.avatar` ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant it only returns one row

Comment: What do you mean by "one result"? If there is only one resulting row, there is only one resulting row. And why do you want to use `SELECT *` if you don't care about all columns?

Comment: Updated the question for clarity, sorry guys. I mean it's only returning one row when there are multiple rows that match the search term. How can I change this to return all matching rows?

Answer (score 0):

My bad.. I was returning `$stmt->fetch();` instead of `$stmt->fetchAll();`.

There's nothing wrong with the query itself.

Hope it helps somebody else if they stumble across something similar.